# Fit element to content width with display:flex;

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider the folowing HTML:

```
<div id="container2">
        <span>Container 2 textWrapped</span>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#container2 { 
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 20%;
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;    
}


#container2>span {      
    
    min-width: 50%;
    max-width: 90%;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;  
}
```

I would like the `span` element to fit the text content. I already try

- `justify-content: space-around;`
- `width: fit-content;`

But I can't figure out how to get get the span width to fit the text content. The red square on the figure should be narrower. The problem appears only when the text is wrapped:

[image]

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/zjdf01nt/10/